# Macro name from shape click

Tags: excel, vba

I have numerous sheets, all with a button which activates a macro.

With VBA, how can I pick up the name of the macro attached to the shape on each sheet?

I have the code to look at each sheet, but can't see how to get the macro name from the shape properties.

Comment: Use the "OnAction" Property of the shape

Answer (score 0):

```
Sub LoopandExamine()
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim s As Shape
For Each ws In Worksheets
    For Each s In ws.Shapes
        If s.OnAction <> "" Then
            Debug.Print s.Name & ";" & s.OnAction
        End If
    Next s
Next ws

End Sub
```

Comment: This was a very speedy response. Many thanks, works perfectly!

Comment: Thank you for this code snippet, which might provide some limited, immediate help. A [proper explanation](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) would greatly improve its long-term value by showing why this is a good solution to the problem and would make it more useful to future readers with other, similar questions. Please edit your answer to add some explanation, including the assumptions you've made.